# Comparing values in two columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on this code that compares column A ( code source) and column B( code roc)   and for each code source in column A it has his code regate in column C  and address in column D so if A=B copy them back in E and F with their code regate in column G and their address in column H .
this the code I am using it blocks until I shut down excel  and it doesn't give me the exact results if anyone can help me thank you 
here is a picture of the result that i need from A and B , C and D

[image]

```
Sub copy_lignes()

  Dim DerLigA, DerLigB  As Long, i, j As Long

    DerLigA = Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DerLigB = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To DerLigA
      For j = 2 To DerLigB
        If Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & j) Then

          Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("E" & i)
          Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("F" & i)
          Sheets("sheet3").Range("C" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("G" & i)
          Sheets("sheet3").Range("D" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("H" & i)

        End If
      Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: are the values in Column A and Column B unique ? I mean. does each value in Column A doesn't repeat itself ? Column B?

Comment: the values in column A are unique but in colmn B they are repeted !

Comment: so if a value in Column A in row 10, matches a value in Column B at row 20, you want to copy values of cells "A:D"to cells "E:H" at row 20 ? or row 10 ?

Comment: no , like if we have x in row 10 in column A and x in row 20 in column B  , copy x in E and in H with their C and D whish are in the same cell as x

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you need. Can you add to your post 2 screen-shots of your simulated sheet, make a manual simulation of before and after a match, how does it look, what value goes to which cell

Comment: @AnasRAFEI, as ShaiRado already said, post examples of a "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: i have added a picture that explain what i need in the link i have updated the poste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, maybe this is what you meant in your post:

```
Sub copy_lignes()

Dim DerLigA, DerLigB  As Long, i, j As Long
Dim PasteRow As Long

' optimize speed performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet3")

    DerLigA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DerLigB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    PasteRow = 2

    For i = 2 To DerLigA
        For j = 2 To DerLigB
            If .Range("A" & i) = .Range("B" & j) Then
                .Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=.Range("E" & PasteRow)
                .Range("B" & j & ":D" & j).Copy Destination:=.Range("F" & PasteRow)
                PasteRow = PasteRow + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

' restore settings 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: it still blocks , untill i shutdown excel , but it gives results near to what i want , the E and F are not the same !

Comment: i have added a picture in the link in my poste for the results that i want

Comment: @AnasRAFEI try now (edited code), should match the results you want

Comment: yes it is doing exactly the job but it blocks excel is it because of the amount of data i am processing ??

Comment: @AnasRAFEI  yes, how many rows do u have ? try now with the 2 lines I added, should be faster when running with  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: in column A i have 9200 row and in B i have 30000 !

Comment: i have tried it but still blocks do i need to use the dictionnary ?

Comment: @AnasRAFEI  that's a LOT, did u try with my edited section? It could still take the code a minute or two to run ~ 270M iterations

Comment: yes i am giving it some time to see how much minute it will take , this work need to be done just once so if it works its all good

Comment: @AnasRAFEI  that's what I wanted to say, if u run this code once a month, and it takes 4-5 minutes to run, just wait. But if u are running it every day, then that's something else

Answer (score -1):

It might be that you just need to tab in a few lines, so it should look like this:

```
Sub copy_lignes()

Dim DerLigA As Long
Dim DerLigB As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 2
j = 2
DerLigA = Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DerLigB = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i To DerLigA
    For j To DerLigB
        If Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & j) Then

            Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("E" & i)
            Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("F" & i)
            Sheets("sheet3").Range("C" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("G" & i)
            Sheets("sheet3").Range("D" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("H" & i)

        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: still the same thing nothing changed !